# Obtaining the variance whose joint density is a little confusing

Tags: statistics, variance

Let

$f(x_1,x_2)=\begin{cases}
\frac{e^{\frac{-x_2^2}{2}}}{x_2\sqrt{2\pi}} & \text{ if } 0<|x_1|\leq x_2<\infty \\ 
0 &  elsewhere
\end{cases}$

It is required to obtain the variance of $x_1$. I am not able to start the problem since the density of $x_1$ looks almost impossible. Please help me to obtain the density , so that I can find the variance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The PDF of $X_1$ is not necessary since, for every $n$, $$E(X_1^n)=\iint x_1^nf(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2$$ This yields readily $$E(X_1)=0$$ by symmetry, and $$E(X_1^2)=\int_0^\infty\int_{-x_2}^{x_2} x_1^2e^{-x_2^2/2}(x_2\sqrt{2\pi})^{-1}dx_1dx_2=\int_0^\infty(2x_2^3/3)e^{-x_2^2/2}(x_2\sqrt{2\pi})^{-1}dx_2=\cdots$$

Comment: And the answer turned out to be after solving the above integral using the gamma transformation is $\frac{1}{3}$.  Thank you so much.

Comment: ...Which is not very surprising since $$(X_1,X_2)=^d(UZ,|Z|)$$ where $(U,Z)$ is independent, $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, and $Z$ is standard normal. Thus, $$E(X_1)=E(U)E(Z)=\tfrac12\cdot0=0\qquad E(X_1^2)=E(U^2)E(Z^2)=\tfrac13\cdot1=\tfrac13$$

Comment: Why can't I think about that? It made the problem very easy. Thank you so much.